# Dates are always utc start in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

I have a data model defined as such in mongoose:

```
var timeTicketSchema = mongoose.Schema({
relatedObjectId : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
startTime : Date,
endTime : Date,
claimed: { type: Boolean, default : false },
claimedOn : Date,
locked : { type : Boolean, default : false },
lockedOn : Date,
bookingId : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
pricePerHour : Number
});
```

And when creating I'm posting in the following format, dates are milliseconds from UTC start:

```
{
"relatedObjectId": "561ee6bbe4b0f25b4aead5c8",
"startTime" : "1448550000000",
"endTime" : "1448551800000"
}
```

However when i look at my created object in mongo, the object doesn't have the correct start and end time:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "564cfb5e7c24fa1100991321"
},
"endTime": {
    "$date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
},
"startTime": {
    "$date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
},
"relatedObjectId": {
    "$oid": "561ee6bbe4b0f25b4aead5c8"
},
"locked": false,
"claimed": false,
"__v": 0
}
```

The insert code is very simple:

```
var timeTicket = new TimeTicket();
timeTicket.tutorId = tutorId;
timeTicket.startTime = new Date(startTime);
timeTicket.endTime = new Date(endTime);

timeTicket.save(function(err, timeTicket){
    if(err){
        return next(err, null);
    }

    return next(null, timeTicket);
});
```

What am i missing where my dates aren't making it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the timestamp to int with **[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** first before converting them to Date:

```
var timeTicket = new TimeTicket();
timeTicket.tutorId = tutorId;
timeTicket.startTime = new Date(parseInt(startTime));
timeTicket.endTime = new Date(parseInt(endTime));

timeTicket.save(function(err, timeTicket){
    if(err){
        return next(err, null);
    }

    return next(null, timeTicket);
});
```